# What to replace for this using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.SQLiteStore

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

We follow this article and it's been running ok https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices%5CTodoAzure/
but then since  yesterday we change the code to allow offline sync - #define OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED and after that we  can't rebuild the solution due to "using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;" below missing assembly ? Now check this on Nuget and apparentlt it's beeing deprecated. So what to change on this then?

```
#if OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
#endif
```

I'm appreciated your input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. Didn't realise that we need to include package for Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore package from Nuget ...looks good now :)